# Complexity and Big-O

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

What is the worst case time complexity for the following two algorithms assuming items has enough unused space that it never needs to be re-sized? My initial guess is that A would run slower because it has to shift every element over to add the new one at index [0]. I think B is O(N^2) in the worst case but am not sure.

A.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        items.add(0, new Integer(i));
```

and B.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        items.add(new Integer(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the underlying data structure that is used to store the items. If you use a linked list, insertion as in A takes constant time, ie O(1) whereas if you used an array, it will be O(n) since you have to shift every elements 1 place to the left to make room for the new item. Therefore the loop will have complexity O(n) if linked list is used and O(n^2) if array is used.

For B, it is not clear how you want to implement the add function, therefore nothing can be said about it's complexity. The complexity differs when you use linked list, array or balanced tree.

Comment: items is an ArrayList<Integer>. But why isn't A O(N^2 or N^3) because it has to shift n(n-1)/2 => n^2 items n times for the loop.

Comment: A is indeed O(N or N^2) because every insertion takes O(1) or O(N). I should have stated that clearly. What do you mean by n^2 items? According to the loop A, you only make N insertion hence you have maximum N items.

Comment: but at the end of the loop for A, once youve gotten all the way through it, you would have had to move n(n-1)/2 numbers because each time youre adding the new number to the front of the list (using an arrayList) as opposed to in B where youre adding it to the end

Comment: The first insertion requires to shift 0 item, the second requires shifting 1 item, the 3rd require shifting 2 items... Altogether, it will take 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1 = n*(n-1)/2 shifts. This is the sum of movement not for each insertion.